# Aws CloudWatch Get Log Group and Log Stream data in python

Tags: python, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Hey guys so I'm basically using python to figure out a way to get the most recent log stream and date of that log stream for every log group. Afterwards I want to be able to display the log group and how many days it has not been written to.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all your log groups with [describe_log_groups](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_groups) and once you have them you can get the most recently modified log stream with [describe_log_streams](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_streams) (you'll need to `orderBy=LastEventTime`, `descending=True`, `limit=1`).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Those are the two methods that I am using in order to create my defined results.

Comment: So what's your question then?

Comment: You answered my question, I came across this answer as well after doing some reading and implementation.